# random.choice selection of list element inside a for loop in python

Tags: python, loops

```
num=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
for c in num:
    print("selected :",random.choice(c))

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

What's wrong with this code? I want a single element in a list to be selected randomly using for loop.

Desired output:

```
selected :3
```

Or

```
selected :6
```

I'm looping a list because if 1 element is selected, I want it to be deleted from the list.

Comment: Why are you looping over the list? Why are you calling `random.choice` on each individual element?

Comment: i am looping the list  because if if  selected 1 element im planning that element to be deleted in a list

Comment: So if you loop, you think you delete that element?

Comment: Selecting 1 of any element is my only problem, coz if i print(c) or print(num) it would gave me 6 element in a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) docs, it accepts a *sequence*.

> **random.choice(seq)**
>
> Return a random element from the non-empty sequence *seq*.
>   If *seq* is empty, raises `IndexError`.

So, it's wrong to pass in each element of `num`, which is an `int`, which will lead to a `TypeError`:

```
  File "/.../python3.8/random.py", line 288, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

You need to pass in `num` itself and then it returns a random element from it.

```
>>> num = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> print("selected :", random.choice(num))
selected : 4
>>> print("selected :", random.choice(num))
selected : 5
>>> print("selected :", random.choice(num))
selected : 2
```

A `for` loop does not make much sense here (hence the questions in the comments) because you don't need to pass each element to `random.choice`.

You said that:

> I'm looping a list because if 1 element is selected, I want it to be deleted in a list.

I'm not sure what is your actual purpose for this, but maybe a `while` loop is more appropriate. For example, you can keep selecting random elements from the list and removing it from the list *while* the list is not empty.

```
>>> num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> while len(num) > 0:
...   n = random.choice(num)
...   print("selected : ", n)
...   num.remove(n)
...   print("num is now: ", num)
... 
selected :  3
num is now:  [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
selected :  5
num is now:  [1, 2, 4, 6]
selected :  4
num is now:  [1, 2, 6]
selected :  1
num is now:  [2, 6]
selected :  6
num is now:  [2]
selected :  2
num is now:  []
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is using `random.shuffle(num)` and then looping over `num` which means every item will be shown once.

```
num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
random.shuffle(num)
for c in num:
    print("selected: ", c)
```